# How to set up a email tracking code that tracks email opens/clicks for different client email providers?

Tags: email, google-analytics, tracking, event-tracking

I would like to track email clicks and opens for different client email sources (e.g.Gmail,Outlook,Yahoo,Apple) and collect the information to my Google Analytics account is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tracking email opens in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456592/tracking-email-opens-in-google-analytics)

Answer (score -1):

You can see that information in the **referral** channel in Google Analytics, however if the clicks come from an installed mail client (e.g. Outlook desktop) the traffic will be **Direct / (none)**, while if it occurs from webmail of Outlook, the **Referral** traffic will be from *live.outlook.com*.

Comment: Hi Michele ,thank you for your feedback but is there any way I can track email click or opens from different email providers?. For instance is i am sending an email via my internal system and i want to track emails opens from anyone who click or open the email. I know that  there is a way by creating an image and inserting some bits of code but this track only email opens and clicks from Outlook and not from Gmail, Yahoo and Apple email  or others. Do you have any further suggestions?